# Laravel HasManyThrough CrossDatabaseRelation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

strange question:
I have 3 Models

1. Order

   ### **with id as PK**
2. Orderline

   ### **with id as PK and order_id as FK. brand and partnumber are two separatet colums**
3. Article
   **with combined PK brand and partnumber**
   **which is on another database **

One Order hasMany Orderlines. Every Orderline hasOneArticle.
i had make a function within order:

```
public function articles()
    {
        $foreignKeys = [
            'brand_id',
            'article_number',
        ];
        $localKeys = [
            'brand',
            'partnumber',
        ];
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\Masterdata\Articles','App\Models\Oms\OrderLine',$foreignKeys,$localKeys,'id','id');
    }
```

How can i retrieve all Attributes from articles through Order?
I tried something like this:

```
    $order = Order::find($orderid)->articles();
    dd($order);
    //did not work
    $order = Order::with('orderlines.articles')->where('id','=',$orderid)->get();
```

Do you have an idea for me?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure more than one database in the `database.php` config, and specify the `$connection` name in the Model class.

For the most part, Eloquent doesn't do JOINs, it just does IN statements on the key values from the preceding query, and programmatically marries the results together after the fact. Partly to avoid the mess of keeping table aliases unique, and partly to offer this kind of support- that your relations don't need to live in the same database.

In other words, what you have there should work just fine. If there's a specific error getting thrown back though, please add it to your post.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works. I had edit my question ;-)

Comment: No problem! Also, `$order = Order::find($orderid)->articles();` would not work because your call to the `articles()` method would return the `Relation` object, it wouldn't actually execute the query. The idea is, it's not going to assume you don't want to append additional conditions to the Relation Query. All it assumes is that you want its foreign key pre-filled with the result from `Order::find()`. To get the actual result, you could do `$order = Order::find($orderid)->articles()->get();`, or the "dynamic property" shortcut `$order = Order::find($orderid)->articles;`